# Outlook (desktop) addin: Reasons for null Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress?

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We have run into a few situations where the Office.js API (the Outlook addin API) is returning null values for Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress and Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName. In these situations our addin can't continue its initialization. What could cause the Office.js API to return those null values?

This happens for Exchange Online users/mailboxes provided by Microsoft through AppRiver and only in Outlook (desktop). Correct values are returned when our addin runs in their OWA.

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    var userProfile = Office.context.mailbox.userProfile;
   }
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: For properties like the ones you mentioned, Outlook sends those values to the add-in after its webpage is loaded, and before [Office.initialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office#initialize-with-officeinitialize) is called. Is your add-in's initialization code setup to run within or after Office.initialize?

Comment: And just to clarify, the full names of the APIs are Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress and Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName.

Comment: In this case it's a hosted (by AppRiver) MS Exchange server. Our addin waits for Office.initialize to execute and then queries  Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress

Comment: By "waits for Office.initialize to execute" I meant to finish by calling our callback function. So our queries happen when the Office API is supposed to be initialized.

Comment: Sounds like it's not an issue with the timing of the call. Can you check what version of Exchange the provider is hosting ([steps to check in Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/determine-the-version-of-microsoft-exchange-server-my-account-connects-to-d427465a-ce3b-42bd-9d83-c7d893d5d334))? And which version(s) of Outlook do you see the issue on?

Comment: >Outlook sends those values to the add-in after its webpage is loaded, and before Office.initialize is called
Is it possible that Office.initialize is clearing those properties then? Could there be a reason for it to do so? I believe we're experiencing this mainly for Outlook Mac users.

Comment: Microsoft is the provider, it is Exchange Online! As for the Outlook version I need to ask.

Comment: In one instance it is Outlook 2016 v. 1812 (build 11126.20266)

Comment: Mac Outlook version seems to be 16.16

Comment: Thanks for providing these version numbers. Could you please share your code snippet so that we can provide further assistance?

Comment: You provided a version number for both windows and mac but you mentioned earlier that this issue happens only on Mac. Which client is really affected? How many users are impacted by this? You also mention that this repros only for AppRiver subscriptions, unfortunately we cannot debug their environment and you will have to reach out to them for support. Do you have any repro steps for Office365 environment for us to try?

Comment: We will never solve the problem this way. There is a Microsoft support engineer assigned to this case from AppRiver. Can you connect with him? I can provide his contact info or ticket number. By the way, AppRiver's environment is Exchange Online. According to AppRiver the mailboxes are hosted by Microsoft so you would have access. Thank you.

Comment: Microsoft Premier Support Ticket #:12912546

Comment: any luck finding the fix for this issue ? Some times I get `null` and sometimes I'm getting nothing.

Comment: No, I have not heard of a fix yet.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed this happen in Outlook for Mac clients where there is a mailbox loaded that has an Exchange 2016 back-end. Could it be that the client-specific `js` file is not returning the property as expected?

In my case, I see that `outlook-mac-16.00.js` is returning the email address and display name as expected with **Office 365** as a backend, but not with Exchange 2016.

Comment: We experience this with some Exchange Online mailboxes managed by AppRiver. In other hosted MS Exchange cases, i.e. hosted by Rackspace,  or standard Office 365 mailboxes, no problems.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexey - Have you tested the same with latest Office insider build? I don't have Exchange on-premise server or hosted; rather i tested with Office 365, it works for me. Alternately you can check Outlook diagnostics or charles Web Proxy logs and see what you notice for the affected users in it...

Comment: Yes, personally I use the insider build (Mac) and everything works just fine. Our addin has been validated and approved by the Office store team many times too. Something is special in the Exchange Online setup provided by Microsoft for AppRiver.

Comment: So the issue doesn't sounds to be with your app or API call, rather environment/provider specific. I am not sure the given NLB (network load balancers) or any specific .js file or setup (like impersonation or delegation) which is making difference. I would say they're worth to check.